# Upgrading from 10.04 Server to 14.04

Tags: server, grub2, upgrade, 10.04, raid

I have an Ubuntu dedicated server hosted at GoDaddy.

I wish to make an upgrade from 10.04 to 14.04, however each time I login over SSH, I get the notice to be careful if I upgrade because I have RAID.

So, I wish to know where I need to be careful.

I presume that is on installation of GRUB or kernel, but I don't know what I need to do for RAID hard disks.

Can someone please tell me more about this specification?

Thanks

(I haven't tried anything)

Comment: Notice that if you want to upgrade to 14.04 you have to upgrade to 12.04 first.

Comment: and about RAID? I understand that ok i need to upgrade to 12.04 first, but and about RAID specification? I need to be carefull about what ?
*** Thanks for youre feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that software RAID only replicates the partitions, not the MBR, so if you re-install grub you need to make sure that you install it to both drives. You also need to make sure that, when you install grub to the second drive, you configure it as if it were the first drive (so that if the first drive fails you can disconnect it and the second drive will boot).

```
# grub
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sda
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sdb
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
grub> quit
```

Note that each drive is configured as if it were the first drive (hd0).